# React+Redux. Не получается получить данные при помощи fetch

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Начал осваивать Redux и applyMiddleware. Попробовал написать свою простенькую программу. И получил ошибку, в логах пишет, что данные json до моего компонента-контейнера не доходят, т.е. undefined. Возможно я упустил что-то элементарное.

**index.js:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducer from './reducers/index';
import App from "./components/App";

const store = createStore(
 reducer,
 applyMiddleware(thunk)
 )

console.log(store.getState()) // тут выводит только пустой объект

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('store updated', store.getState());  // обновлений стора нет, в консоль ничего не выводит
 });

ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
 </Provider>,
 document.getElementById('root')
 )
```

**action:**

```js
export const REQUEST_DATA = 'REQUEST_DATA';
export const RECEIVE_DATA = 'RECEIVE_DATA';

export const requestData = () => ({
type: REQUEST_DATA,
});

export const receivedData = json => ({
type: RECEIVE_DATA,
json: json,
});


export function fetchPosts() {
 return function (dispatch) {
   dispatch(requestData());
   return fetch(`http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ceRHciXcVu?indent=2`)
   .then(
      response => response.json(),
      error => console.log('An error occurred.', error),
  )
   .then((json) => {
      dispatch(receivedData(json));
   },
  );
 };
}
```

**reducer:**

```js
import { REQUEST_DATA, RECEIVE_DATA } from '../actions/index';

const reducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_DATA:
       return { ...state, loading: true };
    case RECEIVE_DATA:
       return { ...state, json: action.json };
    default:
       return state;
  }
};
export default reducer;
```

**container:**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

let App = ({filteredArr}) => {
  console.log({filteredArr}); // получаю undefined

  return(
    <p>test</p>
  )
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    filteredArr: state.json
  })
  
  App = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    null
  )(App)
  
export default App;
```

Comment: Вы нигде не вызываете fetchPosts...

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, код был валидный, просто нигде не было вызова fetchPosts. Добавил в компонент кнопку, на нее поцепил fetchPosts и стор начал обновляться.

Comment: Вам при такой постановке (это правильная постановка) нужно использовать последнюю версию реакта совместно с useRedux из react-redux и fetchPosts вызывать в хуке useEffect, приблизительно так useEffect(fetchPosts, [])